# Finding convergence using the root test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

There's an extra credit assignment for my Calc 2 class that requires using the ratio and root test to find a function's convergence. I successfully used the ratio test to find the function converges absolutely, however, when trying to use the root test I get stuck. The equation is $$\sum_{1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{2^n}$$ Can you give me a hint on how to start, both methods I attempted to use to solve this problem did not pan out. One of the methods was inconclusive. I know that this is possible however I just want to be sure.

Comment: "I successfully used the root test ..., however, when trying to use the root test ..."  Did you mean to say "root test" both times?

Comment: Could you show your work that did not pan out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ratio Test: $$ L_1 = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left| \frac{(n+1)^2}{2^{n+1}} \cdot \frac{2^n}{n^2} \right| =
> \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(n+1)^2}{2n^2} = \frac{1}{2}$$
>
> Root Test: $$ L_2 = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left| \frac{n^2}{2^n} \right| ^ \frac{1}{n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^{\frac{2}{n}}}{2} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(n^{\frac{1}{n}})^2}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Theorem: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$

by the ratio and root test you can conclude that the series converges as $L_1 = \frac{1}{2} \lt 1$ and $L_2 = \frac{1}{2} \lt 1$

Comment: "n \rightarrow \infty" gives $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n=\frac{n^2}{2^n}$, and now you need to find out whether $\sum a_n$ converges or not. By the root test you can get to here;

$$\begin{aligned}L&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n^2}}{2} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n^2} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n}*\sqrt[n]{n} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{n \to \infty}exp(log (n^{1/n})*exp(log (n^{1/n}) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{n \to \infty}exp\left(\frac{log(n)}{n}\right)*exp\left(\frac{log(n)}{n}\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{n \to \infty}exp(0)^2 \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\end{aligned}$$
As $L<1$, the series is absolutely convergent.